# Android Studio Mac keymap doesn't work on Windows

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, ide, intellij-14

I use Mac at home and use Windows at work. On my Windows machine, I have tried changing my Android Studio keymap in Settings to Mac OS X 10.5+ but the Windows key is not detected as Meta. Also, when I use Mac keyboard, the command key is detected as Windows key. What key should I use as Meta key on Windows? How can I config Android Stuido or Intellij such that I can use Mac keymap on Windows?

Thanks!

Comment: Just moved today from my old mac to window =(, did you found any solution for this?

Comment: @shem unfortunately, no, not yet.

Comment: It's 2016 and this is still a problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post: [How to make Windows key the IntelliJ IDEA Command/Meta key under Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32921994/how-to-make-windows-key-the-intellij-idea-command-meta-key-under-windows)

You can remap the windows key in IntelliJ/Android Studio by going to Help->Edit Custom properties and adding this following to the file:

```
keymap.windows.as.meta=true
```

Then restart and you should be good to go.

Comment: I guess it depends on if the shortcut is overridden by some other commands.

Comment: is about an open bug with intelliJ