# Disable Windows 10 Shortcuts (Windows key remapped as Meta Key)

Tags: windows, macos, intellij-idea

I'm trying to set the windows key as a meta key for my IntelliJ IDEA settings. I've been following the steps here
[How to make Windows key the IntelliJ IDEA Command/Meta key under Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32921994/how-to-make-windows-key-the-intellij-idea-command-meta-key-under-windows)
but as i'm using windows 10, the windows shortcuts take precedence before ideas shortcut, making it unusable. 
I've tried to disable the windows key, but that also makes the key disabled in IDEA.

I need a way to disable the shortcuts, but not the key itself.

Comment: check "solution 10" from https://windowsreport.com/disable-windows-key/

Comment: i've tried solution 10 and solution 11 :( still the same issue, but now some metas are working. Meta + C is working, Meta + V isn't :(

Comment: did you activate `keymap.windows.as.meta=true`? you can do it `ctrl+shift+a` -> registry and search for this and activated. Note: all the changes in registry are not to mess with and can create other issues.

Comment: Yes, i've done that, but isn't working, idea now sees the windows key as meta, my problem is that some shortcuts (like windows + X) is picked up by the windows and not passed to the IDE :(

Comment: even when you activated solution 10 or 11? because this should not be the case anymore.

Comment: yes, even when i've activated both. I manage to disable some shortcuts, but even if there is no action for windows, it doesn't send them to idea.
Ex: I've disabled Windows + X, nothing happens anymore but IDEA doesn't receive the event that those key were pressed.